# Convert meters to kilometers and format the value in Viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have the Viewmodel:

```
public class PartnerSearchResultVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public string Classification { get; set; }
}
```

I get the distance in meters from the database like this: 2354,58764478263 m

I would like to present 2.35 km

How change the Viewmodel to make the convertion there (if it's the best place to do it)

Comment: is the `,` in your meters a mistake or are you actually switching locales as well as the distance conversion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd add a read-only property to your model.

```
public double Kilometers { get { return this.Distance / 1000; } }
```

If you want a formatted string back I'd create a second readonly property.

```
public string KilometerDisplay { 
    get { 
        return String.Format("{0:0.00}km", this.Kilometers); 
    } 
}
```

Although, depending on your use case, a generalized format function might be appropriate.  Perhaps as an extension method:

```
[Extension]
public string FormatDistance(this double distance) {
    return distance.FormatDistance("");
}

[Extension]
public string FormatDistance(this double distance, string unitString) {
    return return String.Format("{0:0.00}{1}", distance, unitString);
}
// for meters:   result.Distance.FormatDistance("m");
// for kilometers:  result.Kilometers.FormatDistance("km");
```

Then add some XML documentation to the `Distance` property explaining that it is in meters.

Comment: Instead of a double, I'd use a string and return 2.35km as a string since the Distance property already stores the exact value and in this context the OP is looking to format an output. But the pattern's good!

Comment: Hi @Dan thanks. How would you apply the format to #.## ?

Comment: You prefer String.Format or DataAnnotation?

Comment: That's difficult to answer without being familiar with your project.  Choose the technology that is most appropriate to your situation.

Comment: @Dan-o Out of curiosity, why are you adding the `ExtensionAttribute` to your extension methods?  The attribute is redundant in C# as the compiler automatically decorates such methods.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Gjeltema: I'm a VB guy.  VB has no automatic decoration of extension methods.  So the primary reason is I didn't know about that particular C# feature.  The second reason is I think it makes things more readable.  I know many C# devs will disagree with that - to each their own.